# Transpose column to row in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to convert the column into row using SQL query.

I have table with below structure. Table data:

[image]

and I need to convert column value into rows like below

Expected data structure:

[image]

All help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Use pivot in sql server

Answer (score 2):

This is an unpivot-repivot problem.  Here is a solution:

```
select v.id,
       max(case when t.id = 1 then v.val end) as val_1,
       max(case when t.id = 2 then v.val end) as val_2,
       max(case when t.id = 3 then v.val end) as val_3,
       max(case when t.id = 4 then v.val end) as val_4,
       max(case when t.id = 5 then v.val end) as val_5
from t cross apply
     (values ('Run', run),
             ('Temp', temp),
             ('RG', RG),
             ('FF', FF)
     ) which (id, val)
group by v.id;
```

Comment: @rubanpradeep . . . I don't understand what you are asking in your comment.  Perhaps you should ask another question.